# How to get major & minor version limit of list/library using javascript?

Tags: list, javascript, document-library, versioning, version-history

How to get **Major Limit** of Sharepoint List and both **Major & Minor Limit** of Sharepoint Library using ***javascript*** ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately only SharePoint Online CSOM API (v.16) supports those properties currently for List object:

- `List.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit`
- `List.MajorVersionLimit`

In SharePoint On Premise, you could consider the following approach to return those properties:

```
getListInfo('Documents',
       function (info) {
          console.log(info.MajorVersionLimit);  //Keep the following number of major versions 
          console.log(info.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit); //Keep drafts for the following number of major versions
       },
       function (sender, args) {
          console.log(args.get_message());
       }
    );
```

where

```
function getListInfo(listTitle,success,error)
{
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    ctx.load(list,'SchemaXml');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {
          var schemaXml = list.get_schemaXml();
          success(schemaXml2Json(schemaXml));
       },
       error);
}


function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: "only SharePoint Online CSOM API (v.16) supports those properties currently for List object": are you sure? I've tested my code (both the managed and JavaScript version), and both seemed to function on version February 2015 PU on-premise. The properties are decorated with the ClientCallable attribute in the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList class, and available in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List class as well.

Comment: Hm, probably i'm mistaken then, cant confirm when those properties have been added..  but at least in CSOM 15.0.4535.1000 they are not available.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access this information via the `MajorVersionLimit` and `MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit` properties of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List` object.

For example (managed OM):

```
string url = "http://yoursite/subweb";
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
    var web = clientContext.Web;

    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("YourDocLib");

    clientContext.Load(list, l => l.MajorVersionLimit, l => l.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit);                
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Major version: [{0}]; Major with minor version: [{1}]", list.MajorVersionLimit, list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit);
}
```

JavaScript OM:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("YourDocLib");
ctx.load(list, 'MajorVersionLimit', 'MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit');

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        console.log("Major version: [" + list.get_majorVersionLimit() + "]; Major with minor version: [" + list.get_majorWithMinorVersionsLimit() + "]");
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
);
```

As @Vadim Gremyachev pointed out in his answer, the availability of these properties seems to be dependent on the patch level of your farm. For example, they are not exposed in the client object model in the SP1 version (15.0.4569.1506) as far as I see, but are available in the February 2015 PU (15.0.4693.1001) on which I've tested my code samples.

Comment: The question specifically mentions javascript. This i CSOM in C#. I know the API is the same, but can you possibly convert this code snippet to JSOM?